# Flow of arguments(The way pair of arguments are sent) from the container to the binary predicate function in a certain algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, arguments, undefined-behavior, definition

when we want an algorithm to behave based on our own requirements on a container.Then we create our very own Binary Predicate function,my code includes `bool twice(int e1,int e2){ return e1*2 == e2}` on list `L ={30,50,15,10,20,80,90}`in the below code,I've used `adjacent_find(L.begin(),L.end(),twice)` algorithm to find the pair of integers where the first one is twice the second.Here I am unable to understand how the passing of arguments takes place? does (30,50) is sent to binary predicate?if Yes,then what is the next pair of arguments that is sent?is it (30,15) then (30,10)---(30,90),or (50,15) then (15,10)---(80,90),How does the algorithm decides the flow in which arguments are send?what are they?Does the algorithm stops performing its respective task as soon as it encounters return value of binary predicate as 'true'?Could anyone explain me how the passing of arguments takes place between container elements and binary predicate ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

bool twice(int e1,int e2)
{
    return e1 * 2 == e2;
}
int main()
{
    std::list<int> L ={30,50,15,10,20,80,90};
    std::list<int>::iterator i;

    i = std::adjacent_find(L.begin(),L.end(),twice);
    if(i==L.end())
        std::cout<<"There are not two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first.\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"Two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first are:"<<*(i++)<<" & "<<*(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [description of std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) explains what it does, and how. What part of that description is unclear to you? How many possible ways are there to interpret "two consecutive identical elements". Is 30 and 15 "consecutive" in your example? Of course not, so why would you expect adjacent_find to use the predicate to compare them?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks alot,I have figured out where exactly I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

As the name of algorithm implies adjacent elements are considered. For the list from your example

```
{ 30, 50, 15, 10, 20, 80, 90 }
```

the adjacent elements are

```
( 30, 50 ), ( 50, 15 ), ( 15, 10 ), ( 10, 20 ), ( 20, 80 ), ( 80, 90 )
```

As soon as the first adjacent pair of elements that satisfies the binary predicate is found the algorithm stops its execution and returns the iterator that points to the first element of the pair.

Take into account that this statement

```
std::cout<<"Two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first are:"<<*(i++)<<" & "<<*(i);
```

results in undefined behavior because there is no sequence point between evalutions of these expressions `*(i++)` and `*(i)`.

To understand how the algorithm works it is useful to write it yourself.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator adjacent_find( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, BinaryPredicate binary_predicate )
{
    auto next = first;

    if ( first != last && ++next != last )
    {
        while ( next != last && not binary_predicate ( *first, *next ) )
        {
            ++first;
            ++next;
        }            
    }

    return next == last ? next : first;
}

int main()
{
        std::list<int> lst ={ 30, 50, 15, 10, 20, 80, 90 };
        auto twice = []( const auto &e1, const auto &e2 )
        {
            return 2 * e1 == e2;
        };

        auto it = ::adjacent_find( std::begin( lst ), std::end( lst ), twice );

        if ( it == std::end( lst ) )
        {
            std::cout << "There are not two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first.\n";
        }            
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first are: "
                      << *it << " & " << *std::next( it ) << '\n';
        }                      
}
```

The program output is

```
Two adjacent elements where the second is twice the first are: 10 & 20
```